# Outsourced Multiparty computation proof in Ideal world

Tags: provable-security, security-definition

I need to know in an outsourced two party computation where honst $A$ and $B$ outsource their private and secure data to a malicious server, why we need to design a simulator **that interacts with an adversary** who exists in real model?

See the paper cited below as an example:

https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/272.pdf

Comment: you need to design the simulator in order to prove security. See [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3816/706)

Comment: The start of section 4 of the paper you linked to has a pretty good explanation.